# Como funciona a sessão em navegadores web?

Tags: segurança, session, aplicação-web, cookies

Uma sessão permite, por exemplo, que eu permita ao usuário permanecer logado, guardando a informação de quem está logado (usuario_id, por exemplo).

Acredito que seja algo mais elaborado do que *cookies*, porque senão eu poderia modificar o *cookie* "usuario_id" do meu navegador para um número qualquer, e assim poderia me logar como outro usuário.

- Como a sessão funciona?
- O que a diferencia dos *cookies*?
- O que a torna segura?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## O que é a sessão

Em projetos web, uma *sessão* consiste na utilização de uma aplicação por um usuário, compreendendo geralmente uma sequência de requisições.

Por outro lado, o termo *sessão* também pode se referir ao conteúdo, local ou variável de armazenamento do *estado* armazenado. Por exemplo, em Java há o *mapa de sessão*, em PHP a variável superglobal `$_SESSION` e assim por diante.

## Como a sessão funciona

Para identificar que a sequência de ações são provenientes do mesmo usuário, utiliza-se alguma técnica para identificá-lo, sendo as mais comuns:

1. ***Cookies***: um identificador de sessão é colocado num *Cookie*, que persistirá pelo menos até o usuário deslogar ou fechar o navegador. Lembrando que os dados de *Cookies* são enviados do navegador ao servidor a cada requisição.
2. **Reescrita de URL**: um identificador de sessão é gerado no primeiro acesso ao sistema e todos os links do sistema adicionam esse identificador como parâmetro de URL. Dessa forma, em cada requisição consegue identificar o usuário.

Percebe-se então que o procedimento geral é gerar um `id` único por usuário e então fazer com que toda requisição informe este `id` de alguma forma, através do qual a linguagem, o framework ou o servidor possam armazenar e recuperar o *estado* da sessão do usuário.

## O que a torna segura

**Nada**. Existem vários ataques fáceis de realizar em sistemas que confiam somente na sessão para autenticar e autorizar usuários. O mais comum é o [**sequestro de sessão**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking). Basta obter de alguma forma o *Cookie* ou URL que contenha o identificador de sessão e colocá-la em outro navegador qualquer.

A segurança, contudo, pode ser implementada de forma razoavelmente eficiente com criptografia assimétrica (HTTPS/SSL). Certificados assinados por autoridades certificadores (CA's) também podem ser usados para garantir que a conversa realmente está sendo feita com quem você espera e não com um "estranho". Além disso, o conteúdo dos *Cookies* não poderia ser interceptado por um intermediário entre cliente e servidor, pois somente os verdadeiros agentes poderiam descriptografar os dados com a chave privada.

O padrão de *Cookies* especifica um parâmetro `secure` que força um *Cookie* a somente ser enviado se a conexão for segura (HTTPS). Isso pode dar uma certa garantia de que ele não vai "escapar" por engano em alguma requisição HTTP comum ao servidor.

Enfim, não sou especialista em segurança. Certamente há muitos detalhes pertinentes a este assunto, mas espero que esta seja uma boa introdução.

Comment: +1, muito bom conteúdo. Entretanto, ressalva - uma URL requisitada sob HTTPS é, sim, encriptada. Ela é parte do request payload. O nome do servidor pode ser determinado já que uma conexão TCP inicial (que é onde SSL/TLS acontece) é necessária para o handshake.

Comment: @OnoSendai Tem razão. Fiz uma confusão feia com a URL lembrando de um caso que já vi onde o log de um proxy poderia ser usado para roubar a sessão, mas realmente não era  HTTPS.

Comment: Na verdade você está correto caso a comunicação entre o client e proxy ocorra via HTTP e o proxy aproveite o NATing para fazer o switch para HTTPS - o Proxy neste caso saberia qual URL foi utilizada.

Comment: Há casos também que o gerenciamento da sessão se dá por um id  inserido dentro da própria página HTML.

Comment: @InaelRodrigues Bem lembrado. Esta é uma técnica bastante utilizada para manter *uma sessão por aba". Entretanto, o id ainda é enviado via cookie, parâmetro de url ou como parte do corpo em cada requisição. O que muda é basicamente o escopo da sessão.

Answer (score 13):

Sessões geralmente dependem de cookies, mas os dados são guardados no servidor. Funciona assim:

1. Uma sessão é iniciada no servidor, que envia um cookie ao browser com um ID único daquela sessão.
2. Qualquer dado associado à sessão é armazenado no servidor, associado a esse ID.
3. Em toda requisição, o browser envia de volta o cookie com o ID da sessão, o que permite ao servidor dar acesso aos dados associados àquele ID.

Portanto, usar sessões é um pouco mais seguro que guardar dados diretamente em cookies, já que se alguém tiver acesso ao cookie não tem acesso direto aos dados (isso sem falar que não cabem muitos dados nos cookies). Porém, se alguém tem acesso aos cookie com o ID da sua sessão, é possível "sequestrar" a sessão e fazer o servidor entregar os dados. Isso é conhecido como [*session hijacking*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking).

Comment: E se eu desativar os cookies do navegador a sessão simplesmente não funciona?

Comment: É, não funciona... Por isso os sites usam sessão (como qualquer site com login) exigem cookies ativados.

Comment: Interessante, nunca tinha me atentado a isso. Grato pela resposta.

Comment: Isso não completamente verdade - cookieless sessions também existem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273066/what-are-cookieless-sessions

Comment: @OnoSendai É mesmo, não tinha pensado nisso. Encaixei um "geralmente" na resposta.

Answer (score 5):

Nos meus projetos mais simples utilizo cookies para que o usuário permanece logado, para evitar o problema relatado por você faço da seguinte maneira.

- O usuário entra com seu login e senha e com a opção de permanecer
  logado.
- Esses dados chegam no servidor ( Usuário, Senha, IP, Browser e outros dados de segurança ) junto com uma variável que utilizo como a resposta para o usuário permanecer online.
- Com uma função gero um código aleatório que também fica armazenada no banco de dados e esse mesmo código é guardado nos cookies do usuário.
- Quando o usuário entra no site novamente verifico a sessão pegando o código que está guardado no cookie e comparando no banco de dados se o usuário esta no mesmo IP e navegador ao qual foi armazenado a sessão. E complementando verifico se a variável de sessão está como 1 (true).
- Quando o usuário deseja sair não precisa nem apagar o cookie, basta atribuir um 0 (false) no banco de dados e o cookie que continha o código não vale mais para uma sessão.

Resumindo, você não guarda os dados de login do usuário no cookie, apenas um código e na tabela dados de verificação como ID, IP, navegador, localização, etc (Evite guardar senhas nesse banco de dados).

Espero ter ajudado. Qualquer duvida, estou a disposição.