# acessar uma página via https perde variáveis de sessão?

Tags: ssl, https, session

Boa tarde.
Tenho uma aplicação rodando na internet e gostaria que algumas páginas fossem rodadas por https e não http.
Estou testando assim: entro na aplicação numa página http. Esta página http chama uma página https.
Quando entro nesta página https verifiquei que as variáveis de sessão são perdidas.
É assim mesmo que funciona ou estou fazendo algo errado? 
Posso fazer assim, chamar apenas algumas páginas via https ou tenho que rodar toda a aplicação em https?
Obrigada

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26610/como-funciona-a-sessão-em-navegadores-web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podem ser três problemas aí.

#### 1. Domínio ou subdomínio diferentes entre HTTP e HTTPS

O mais provável é que as páginas estejam em domínios ou subdomínios separados. Daí não é questão do HTTP/HTTPS em si, mas sim que o navegador considera que são dois servidores distintos, e por isso não encaminha o *cookie* do domínio 1 (que por acaso é HTTP) para o domínio 2 (que por acaso é HTTPS).

#### 2. Cookies estão indo, mas aplicações não compartilham dados de sessão

Depois de verificar se o *cookie* de sessão está chegando nos dois servidores, é preciso verificar se os dois servidores estão gravando/carregando os dados de sessão do mesmo lugar (uma mesma pasta compartilhada, o mesmo banco de dados, um mesmo memcached).

Ou seja, se o *cookie* estiver certo mas a linguagem não consegue acessar os dados, então vai abrir uma sessão vazia mesmo.

#### 3. Cookies `secure` e não `secure` misturados

Quando for conferir se o *cookie* de sessão está chegando nos dois servidores, repare se ele são rigorosamente os mesmos, ou se por acaso um deles contem a tag `secure`.

Cookies `secure` por padrão não são enviados em conexões HTTP, de forma que você pode estar recebendo um cookie diferente na conexão HTTPS que não vai na conexão HTTP.

Comment: Olá. Obrigada pela resposta.
Comentando: as páginas estão na mesma pasta. A exemplo1 (http) chama a exemplo2 (https), que estão no mesmo local. Não estou usando cookies. Estou usando variáveis de sessão tipo Session("nome") - as páginas estão construídas em asp clássico. Se você tiver mais alguma dica agradeço.

Comment: Não entendo nada do uso de ssl mas eu desconfio que descobri o que está acontecendo... Estou testando com um ssl compartilhado, que muda o endereço de minha página e não apenas troca o http por https. Deve ser por isso que perde as variáveis de sessão...

Comment: Sim, que é o ponto número 1, domínios diferentes. O navegador nada sabe se os arquivos estão no mesmo diretório. Para o navegador (e os cookies) só importam se é o mesmo domínio, o que aparece na URL do navegador. Veja aí se não consegue por o site todo em HTTPS.

Comment: Muito obrigada!
Estou vendo para adquirir um certificado próprio.
Abraços

Comment: Accept na resposta? A solução local depende da configuração do servidor web específico, mas a resposta responde a razão geral, e pelo menos encaminha como solucionar.