# Como continuar incrementando o valor de uma variável mesmo depois que uma página é recarregada?

Tags: php

Queria colocar para acrescentar `+1` na variável `$a` toda vez que a página for carregada.

Já usei o código:

```
  $a = ++$a;
  echo $a
```

e também o:

```
  $a = $a++;
  echo $a
```

Mas só adiciona uma vez e, quando atualizo a página, ela não adiciona mais nada. Alguém pode me dar uma sugestão?

Comment: cara ta totalmente desorganizada sua pergunta, mas vou te dar uma dica: use `for`: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.for.php

Comment: Tenta ser mais claro na pergunta, especifica melhor o que você procura.

Comment: Nenhuma das resposta foram aceitas, nenhuma te ajudou?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$txt="";
$arquivo="";
$visitas="";

    $txt        = "contador.txt";
    $arquivo    = fopen($txt,"a+");
    $visitas    = fgets($arquivo,1024);
    fclose($arquivo);

    $arquivo    = fopen($txt,"r+");
    $visitas    = $visitas + 1;
    fwrite($arquivo,$visitas);
    fclose($arquivo);  


    echo "Esta página foi visitada $visitas vezes";
```

A função [**fopen**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fopen.php) abre o arquivo especificado na variável `$txt`.

O modo  `r+` abre para leitura e escrita; coloca o ponteiro do arquivo no começo do arquivo.

A função   [**fgets**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fgets.php)  retorna uma linha de um arquivo aberto com o comprimento especificado (opcional - especifica o número de bytes para ler). O padrão é de 1024 bytes.

A função [**fwrite**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fwrite.php) permite a escrita em arquivos,

**Essa resposta atende o comentário do autor na resposta do David Santos**.

> voce poderia me dar um exemplo de como fazer isso para guardar em um arquivo txt – romulo henrique 9/07 às 2:44

Comment: Eu não sei se a edição foi por conta da minha crítica, mas na verdade eu imagino que talvez o AP possa não saber o que faz as funções `fopen` e `fclose`... por isso falei que faltou explicação...

Comment: @WallaceMaxters foi por conta do downvote, mas sua observação foi boa. Vou editar e colocar alguma explicação

Comment: Fui eu que negativei. Mas já que se propôs explicar, vou remover. A ideia era só estimular explicar melhor. Algumas pessoas podem pensar que ajuda o AP, mas outros usuários virão por conta desse problema e ficarão com dúvidas sobre o que foi feito na resposta.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Por esse motivo que acho que todo voto negativo deveria ter um comentário para que o autor da resposta possa adequá-la a exemplo do sugerido no seu comentário!

Comment: sensacional, cara. Ficou show de bola a edição. +1

Comment: Graças ao seu comentário!!!!

Answer (score 6):

O script guarda os valores das variáveis apenas em tempo de execução, depois disso o espaço na memória ocupado por elas é liberado. Toda vez que você atualizar a página o script volta ao seu estado original.

Caso queira guardar o valor de uma variável mesmo após atualizar a pagina, será necessário guardar o valor da mesma em um lugar externo ao arquivo, como por exemplo : xml, banco de dados, txt, entre outros...

Comment: ou até mesmo cookies, e sessões.

Comment: voce poderia me dar um exemplo de como fazer isso para guardar em um arquivo txt

Answer (score 6):

Como foi dito pelo [David Santos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/59667), ao recarregar a página os valores não são guardados. Eles são registrados ali apenas em tempo de execução, depois disso são removidos da memória.

Em PHP, existe várias maneiras para se manter valores. Um dois mais comuns para o seu caso seria o uso de Sessão ou Cookies.

Eu optaria pelo uso da sessão. As sessões mantém uma ponte entre o cliente e o servidor, permitindo guardar valores específicos para cada cliente (navegador) que carrega sua página.

No seu caso, poderia ser utilizado a variável `$_SESSION` (como foi citado em uma das respostas, porém sem nenhuma explicação sobre o que seria isso).

Veja:

```
// inicia a sessão. Deve ser colocado antes de todo o código de saída para o 
//navegador e antes de usar a variável super global `$_SESSION

session_start();

// Se existir o índice 'a', incrementa. Se não, define 0  
if (isset($_SESSION['a'])) {

  $_SESSION['a']++;

} else {

  $_SESSION['a'] = 0;

}

// imprime o valor
var_dump($_SESSION['a']);
```

O código acima funcionará da seguinte forma: `$_SESSION` será guardado no servidor, com uma identificação única para o cliente (navegador, que é registrada num Cookie). No `if` temos o `isset` que define se o índice `'a'` existe no `array` de `$_SESSION`. Se existir, ele incrementa os valores. Porém se não existir, nós definimos que ele será `0`.

Assim, toda vez que a página for recarregada, o valor também será modificado e ficará salvo na sessão.

**Veja Mais**:

- [Trabalhar com session sem cookies para prevenir roubo de sessão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/36687/trabalhar-com-session-sem-cookies-para-prevenir-roubo-de-sess%C3%A3o)

Aqui há uma explicação sobre o fato de toda Sessão usar Cookies

- [Como funciona a sessão em navegadores web?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26610/como-funciona-a-sess%C3%A3o-em-navegadores-web/26614#26614)

Sessões são usadas muito para efetuar login de usuários:

- [Qual a melhor maneira de criar um sistema de login com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3571)
- [O que guardar em uma sessão de login?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38920)

## Contador de usuários

Na minha humilde opinião, se você quiser fazer um contador de usuários, como foi assinalado em alguns comentários, creio que a melhor maneira é usando um banco de dados.

- [Como gravar valores no banco de dados MYSQL usando PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219812/como-gravar-valores-no-banco-de-dados-mysql-usando-php)

Answer (score 5):

É fácil, tenta usar o código abaixo:

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['a'])) {
    $_SESSION['a'] += 1;
} else {
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['a'] = 1;
}

echo $_SESSION['a'];
```

Comment: Bom eu pensei nisso, eu sugeri o `for` pra ele, mas depois que vi que ele quer guardar valores mesmo atualizando a página. Acho que `Cookies` também serve.

Comment: É verdade @GuilhermeAlves, cookies também resolve o caso, mas depende do objetivo, se ele quiser que o contador funcione para diferentes usuários, o jeito é armazenar mesmo o contador em algum lugar.

Comment: @FabianoLothor vc poderia me explicar se possiveu como faço para armazenar em um arquivo txt e como faço para ele pegar aquele numero que esta no arquivo txt e adicione +1

Comment: @romulohenrique porque estás a ir pelo caminho mais longo?

Comment: @GuilhermeAlves, tem um jeito mas facil como

Comment: @GuilhermeAlves, eu to querendo que quando uma pessoa entre ele some mas 1 igual aqueles contator de visitas

Comment: @romulohenrique, tem plugins para isto. mas se você quer faze-lo, Fabiano já deu a mão. é só tentar

Comment: Eu acho que é um grande problema você ensinar como fazer, mas não explicar nada em sua resposta @FabianoLothor. Você deve ter percebido que, se o Autor da Pergunta não soube que uma variável não seria incrementada por conta do tempo de excecução, é sinal que ele precisa de uma breve explicação sobre o uso de sessões e afins.

Comment: Isso resolve o problema do AP, mas seria interessante explicar por que isso resolve também.